# Is this the correct way to use eventsource?

Tags: javascript, html, cgi, innerhtml

My CGI (python script) is sending data as below,

```
Event: 1st_event
id: 1234  (auto-gen number)
Data: some actual data for div-1

Event: 2nd_event
id: 423143 (auto-gen number)
Data: Some actual data for div-2
```

using python `CGI` to send data to `HTML`, want to use EventSource to get event-related data.

```html
<body>
    <h1>Info</h1>
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <script>
      var source = new EventSource("/cgi-bin/con5.cgi");
      source.addEventListener('1st_event', function(e) {
        document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML = e.data + "<br>";
        console.log(e.data);
      }, false);

      source.addEventListener('2nd_event', function(f) {
      document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = f.data + "<br>";
        console.log(f.data);
      }, false);
    </script>
</body>
```

I want to update data in 1st event in `div1` and data in 2nd event in `div2`.

Comment: HTML works perfectly fine, issue was with event name having extra space at the end. Which I got to know after printing cgi output in TXT file on CLI. After fixing event spaces in CGI , above HTML worked as it required.